# Padding of a div gets bigger when element inside it is big

Tags: html, css

I would like to place an image on a div which I use for a navigation bar, but when I resize the image to 50px or above, the padding on the div gets bigger as well. I don't like this since the image will either be too small to see or the navigation bar will be too big to look pleasing, any ideas on how to fix this?

```css
.navbar{
    background-color:green;
    padding:20px;   
}
.navbar #image1{
    width:40px;
    margin-left:950px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar'>
    <a href='home.html'>Home</a>
    <a href='1.html'>Profile</a>
    <a href='2.html'>Transactions</a>
    <a href='3.html'><p>Settings</p></a>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' id='image1'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first start by removing
`margin-left:auto`
as the margin will exclude your item from your `navbar`

then apply flex properties to your navbar
`.navbar {display : flex}`
so your `navbar` items become in the same line

I recommend checking out this flex-box guide as well [flexbox properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

can you please share the image's link so we can help you?

also you most edit `margin-left:950px;` to `margin-left: auto;` if you want to center it

and this is an example navbar code (*press run to see what is it*)

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar{
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar li a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar li:hover,
.navbar li a:hover{
  color: #666;
}

.navbar img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px; /*or :auto ; */
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>home</li>
  <li>project</li>
  <li>contact</li>
  <li><a>settings</a></li>
  
  <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/600x600.jpg"/>
</ul>

<br><br><br>
<p>or</p>
<br><br><br>

<ul class="navbar">
  <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/600x600.jpg"/>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>project</li>
  <li>contact</li>
  <li><a>settings</a></li>
  
 
</ul>
```

I think you need to learn the basics before start doing websites

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I mainly dove in web development blind with only some videos and stackoverflow to help me, thats why currently I'm using some unconvential methods.

Comment: oh man, don't worry, it's totally okay, my first navbar was vertical and dotted, but I just practice A LOT after I learn the basics. believe me, you'll be a great developer.